# How do I run compiled java classes with GPU libraries (Jogamp JOCL)?

Tags: java, runtime, gpu

Does anyone know how to run the java code from the command line with dependency on GPU libraries in this case Jogamps JOCL.

I have compiled a test program HelloJOCL.java but I get an error during run time.

I tried 
javac -classpath "./lib/jocl.jar:./lib/jocl-natives-macosx-universal.jar:./lib/jocl-natives-linux-i586.jar:./lib/jocl-natives-linux-amd64.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar" ./HelloJOCL.java

java -classpath "./lib/jocl.jar:./lib/jocl-natives-macosx-universal.jar:./lib/jocl-natives-linux-i586.jar:./lib/jocl-natives-linux-amd64.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar:." 
 HelloJOCL

but get this error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opencl/CLContext 
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

Comment: The main suggestion I have is to isolate your suspect code. Your exception is caused by run-time code resolution. In Java, that could be the Generic List for example, when the object type is resolved in run-time. Again, isolate the code. One way is to remove some code to get you an idea.

Comment: Just went with the simpler
javac -source 7 -classpath "./lib/*:./src/" ./HelloJOCL.java

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding code with try/catch like:

```
try {
} catch (NoClassDefFoundError x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

I admit I never did this.